# finding the larger and smaller number

Tags: c++, c++11

i am trying to find a larger and smaller number but something goes wrong in the last part `if(n1 > n2)`   the out put of that if `statement` gives me arbitrary numbers, do not why?

Source Code:

```
#include"../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    int n1=0, n2=0, num;
    cout << "enter two numbers: " << '\n';
    int i = 1;

    while (i < 2)
    { 
        cin >> num;  
        ++i; 
    }
    cout << "the first number is: "<<n1<<'\t'<<"the second number is: "<<n2<<'\n';

    if (n1 < n2)
    { 
         cout << "the smaller number is: " << n1 << '\n';
         cout << "the larger number is: " << n2 << '\n';
    }

    if (n1 > n2)
    {
        cout << "the1 smaller number is: " << n2 << '/n';
        cout << "the larger  number is: " << n1 << '/n';
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "error" << '\n';
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not taking input into n1 and n0, instead you are inputting into num

```
cin >> num;
```

Remove this part:

```
int i = 1;
while (i < 2) { 
    cin >> num;  
    ++i; }
```

and replace with this

```
cin >> n1 >> n2;
```

and you can enter the two numbers separated by a space

Comment: Plus one for the flashy one line `cin`.

Answer (score 3):

All your input is going to `num`.

Ditch the `while` loop and write

```
cin >> n1;
cin >> n2;
```

instead. Also consider using `if`, `else if` blocks as the program control flow towards the end is odd:

```
if (n1 < n2) { 
    /*ToDo*/
} else if (n2 > n1){
    /*ToDo*/
} else {
    /*they are equal*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or better still create a function to check for greater after you must gotten inputs for the two variables (which is actually the solution to your problem).

The function:

```
int func_check_greater(int num1, int num2){
    return (num1 > num2) ? num1 : num2;
}
```